# limit not working in soql query?

Tags: visualforce, soql, community

anyone help me, limit is not working in soql query. I am using autocomplete component for assignto field. It displays users list based on given letters. i am given limit for 10 users but it showing all users.

my query is

```
var assign=document.getElementById('thepage:fname:pb:pbs:agnTo:asignTo').value;
var query='select Id, Name from user where Name=\''+assign+'\' limit 10';
```

autocomplete field is

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="agnTo">
     <apex:outputLabel value="AssignTo" for="asignTo"/>
     <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
        <div class="requiredInput">
           <div class="requiredBlock" id="agnTo"  ></div>
              <apex:inputtext value="{!assignText}"  id="asignTo" onblur="functionAssignTo();RefreshBusinessUnit();">
                <c:AutoCompleteComp1 objectname="User"  searchField="Name"   autocomplete_textbox="{!$Component.asignTo}" />
                <apex:inputhidden value="{!action.Assigned_To__c}" id="asignTo_lkid"/>
              </apex:inputtext>
              <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="display:none;" styleclass="errorMsg" id="agnTopanel">
                 <strong>Error:</strong> You must enter a value
              </apex:outputPanel>
              <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="display:none;" styleclass="errorMsg" id="validagnTopanel">
                 <strong>Error:</strong> No Mathching Users Found
              </apex:outputPanel>
            </div>
         </apex:outputPanel>
   </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Complete "autocomplete" script is

```
<apex:component controller="PRA_AutoCompleteController">
  <!-- JQuery Files--->
  <!-- 
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   -->

  <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jqueryUI, 'jquery-ui-1.8.21.smoothness/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js')}"  />

  <!-- 
  <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jqueryUI, 'jquery-ui-1.8.21.smoothness/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js')}"  />
   -->
  <apex:styleSheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jqueryUI, 'jquery-ui-1.8.21.smoothness/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css')}" />


  <!-- Attributes Required For Component -->
  <apex:attribute name="objectname" description="The object name you want to look for."     type="String" required="true"/>
   <apex:attribute name="searchfield" description="The search filed you want to look for."     type="String" required="true"/>
  <apex:attribute name="additionalfield" description="Any additional fields you'd like to display."     type="String" required="false"/>
  <apex:attribute name="additionalfilter" description="Any additional filter you'd like to include."     type="String" required="false"/>
  <apex:attribute name="autocomplete_textbox" description="The ID for the Autocomplete List Textbox."     type="String" required="true"/>
  <apex:attribute name="autocomplete_page" description="The page for the Autocomplete."     type="String" required="false"/>
  <style>
    .ui-autocomplete-loading { background: white url('/img/loading.gif') right center no-repeat; }
  </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var sObjects;
        var queryTerm;
        var NoResultsLabel = "No Results"; 
        $(esc('{!autocomplete_textbox}')).autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: function(request, response) {
                        queryTerm = request.term;
                        PRA_AutoCompleteController.findSObjects("{!objectname}","{!searchfield}", request.term, "{!additionalfield}", "{!additionalfilter}", function(result, event){
                            if(event.type == 'exception') {
                                  alert(event.message);
                            } else {
                              //  if (result.length == 0) { 
                               //    sObjects = [NoResultsLabel]; 
                              //  }
                            //  else
                                    sObjects = result;                                 
                               //alert(sObjects);                                
                                 response(sObjects);
                            }
                        });

                   },




             focus: function( event, ui ) {
                    $(esc('{!autocomplete_textbox}')).val( ui.item.{!searchfield} );
                    return false;
                    },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                        var di = ui.item.{!searchfield};
                        if (di.indexOf("amp;") > -1){                         
                                 di = di.replace("amp;",""); 
                                 //alert(di);
                         }

                        //alert("{!additionalfield}");
                        if ("{!additionalfield}"!=""){
                             $.each("{!additionalfield}".split(",") , function(key, value) {
                                di = di + ", " + ui.item[value];
                            });
                        }
                        $(esc('{!autocomplete_textbox}')).val(di);
                        $(esc('{!autocomplete_textbox}_lkid')).val( ui.item.Id );
                        $(esc('{!autocomplete_textbox}_lkold')).val( ui.item.{!searchfield} );
                        if ( "{!autocomplete_page}" == "PIT_NewEditIssue" )
                            getSites();
                        return false;
                    }

         })





         .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

             var entry = "<a>" + item.{!searchfield} ;

            if ("{!additionalfield}"!=""){ 
               $.each("{!additionalfield}".split(",") , function(key, value) {
                    entry = entry + ", " + item[value];

                   });           
           }
            entry = entry + "</a>";
         //   entry = entry.replace(queryTerm, "<b>" + queryTerm + "</b>");
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( entry )
               .appendTo( ul );
        };
    });


    function esc(myid) {
           return '#' + myid.replace(/(:|\.)/g,'\\\\$1');
    }

  </script>

</apex:component>
```

Comment: Suggest you post the full AutoCompleteComp1 source.

Comment: Hi Keith, i added my full AutoCompleteComp1 source can you check it once.

Comment: you had to share your controller code too, I went through your code and I find difficult to relate what is what.